# How to stop re-sending Email when the page refresh

Tags: php

i have a notification system it should show notification and send email once. The page refresh automatically ex myPage.php. I use phpMailer to send the email with a function in myFunction.php i am trying to stop this function to execute every time the page refresh in myPage.php.

```
<?php
 function sendEmail($mail,$empemail,$empname,$adminemail,$superevmail,$subject,$bodycontent,$bodycontent2){
   $mail->Encoding = 'base64';

   $mail->isSMTP();                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication
   $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';   // SMTP username
   $mail->Password = '111';   // SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
   $mail->Port = 587;                    // TCP port to connect to

   // Sender info
   $mail->setFrom($empemail, $empname);
   // $mail->addReplyTo('example@gmail.com', 'name');

   // Add a recipient
   $mail->addAddress($adminemail);//ad

   $mail->addCC($superevmail);
   //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

   // Set email format to HTML
   $mail->isHTML(true);

   // Mail subject
   $mail->Subject = $subject;

   // Mail body content
   $bodyContent = $bodycontent;
   $bodyContent .=$bodycontent2;
   $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

   // Send email
   if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
       echo 'Message has been sent.';
   }

 }

?>
```

I tried to redirect the header like this:

```
  // Send email
   if(!$mail->send()) {
     $to = "http://www.example.com";
   $url = $to;
   print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL=$url\">";
   exit;
   }
```

But it still sends email every time the page: myPage.php" refresh. How can i solve that?

Comment: you never called the function `sendEmail` in the code. Please, add this part

Comment: I use it in another function and it is working well. But I want to prevent resending the email when the page refresh

Comment: if call the function every time tht page loads it wil send the e-mail

Comment: one way to go is start a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and store a key when you send the email, and only send the email when this key is not unseted

Answer (score 0):

You should add your redirection in the else block

```
// Send email
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header("Location: message_sent.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It stilll sends emails every time the page refresh